# WordPress & .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, get

I have a website under WordPress where I've created a new page www.foo.com/section/

The idea is to create a permalink like www.foo.com/param1/type/param2 and with .htaccess use a rewrite rule to: www.foo.com/section/?var1=param1&var2=param2&var3=type

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/section1/([a-z0-9]+)$ /section/?var1=$2&var2=$1&var3=section1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/section2/([a-z0-9]+)$ /section/?var1=$2&var2=$1&var3=section2
```

I got it working in my old web but in the WordPress crashes.

```
#My rules -> copy&paste
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/section1/([a-z0-9]+)$ /section/?var1=$2&var2=$1&var3=section1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/section2/([a-z0-9]+)$ /section/?var1=$2&var2=$1&var3=section2
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've only got a beautiful WordPress' 404 page

I've read several questions here but no one helps me.

Thanks for your time and best regards,

R.

13 Jan

I've created a simple test to check it.

The new structure works with a test case without problems:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^lol/$ project/ [L] #Rule 1
RewriteRule ^foo/$ test/ [L] #Rule 2

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

1. **Rule 1**, I've created a subfolder in WordPress root, named "project" with an index.php echoing "Hi dad" and when type www.foo.com/lol/ it loads that script and echoes the word.
2. **Rule 2**, I've created a new WordPress page, www.foo.com/test/ 
   with a simple string to show, but when I write www.foo.com/foo/ it gives me error 404. It seems that the redirection to a wp pages doesn't works as I expected.

Disclaimer: Of course www.foo.com/test/

Now I'm stucked.

Thanks for your previous responses and future help.

Best regards,

R.

14 Jan

I have new news :)

The new .htaccess that works is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/alternator/([a-z0-9]+)$ ?page_id=554&supplier=$1&reference=$2&ref_type=A [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/starter_motor/([a-z0-9]+)$ ?page_id=554&supplier=$1&reference=$2&ref_type=M [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Instead redirect to "elecfinder/" in the .htaccess I'm pointing to "?page_id=554", at least it doesn't gives me error 440

I'm working on an alternator and starter motors web.

I have a URL that is http://www.elecfinder.com/hitachi/starter_motor/s114850 that really is http://www.elecfinder.com/info/?supplier=hitachi&ref_num=M&reference=s114850, here I load the reference info.

http://wp.elecfinder.com/elecfinder/?reference=s114850&supplier=hitachi&ref_type=M is that web in wp, so my idea is to redirect http://wp.elecfinder.com/hitachi/starter_motor/s114850/ to this.

Now I'm able to redirect http://wp.elecfinder.com/hitachi/starter_motor/s114850 to http://wp.elecfinder.com/elecfinder/?page_id=554&supplier=hitachi&ref_num=M&reference=s114850 but there are 2 problems:

1. It changes the url to http://wp.elecfinder.com/elecfinder/ instead maintain wp.elecfinder.com/hitachi/starter_motor/s114850
2. Misses the GET parameters "reference","supplier" and "ref_type"

Thanks for your time.

Best regards,

R.

Comment: Your rules are before `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\s-.()&]+)/(section1|section2)/([a-z0-9]+)$ section/?var1=$1&var2=$3&var3=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Always put your rules after **RewriteEngine on**.
And, in this case (WordPress), be sure to put your rules **before** WordPress' rule (it is here to redirect everything to index.php because WordPress has a front controller and it manages rewriting itself).

Comment: It worked with external folders from wordpress project, but if I try to redirect to a wp page, fails.

I've added more info in the beggining.

Thanks :)

Comment: In your test, it should be ^foo/$ (with a slash) because you're trying to access www.foo.com/foo/. Otherwise, if you want to access www.foo.com/foo (without trailing slash), you would have ^foo$

Comment: It was a mistake copying the string. In the .htaccess it's ok.

Comment: It returns 404 because it has to go through front controller (your index.php). I don't think you can do that directly. You should redirect to index.php with needed parameters to point to your wp page.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? Please.

Comment: I need more info about your wp page (code, url). Can you explain in details why you want to redirect directly to a wp page ?

Comment: Okay, tomorrow I'll give you a detailed answer.

Thanks for all.